# SQL - I need to see how many users are associated with a specific set of ids

Tags: sql, list, compare

I'm trying to identify a list of users that all have the same set of IDs from another table.

I have users 1, 2, 3, and 4, all that can have multiple IDs from the list A, B, C, and D. I need to see how many users from list one have ONLY 3 IDs, and those three IDs must match (so how many users from list one have ONLY A, B, and C, but not D).

I can identify which users have which IDs, but I can't quite get how to get how many users specifically have a specific set of them

Here is the SQL that I'm using where the counts just aren't looking correct. I've identified that there are about 7k users with exactly 16 IDs (of any type), but when I try to use this sql to get a count of a specific set of 16, the count I get is 15k.

```
select  
count(user_id)  
from  
(  
SELECT   
    user_id   
    FROM user_id_type  
    where user_id_type not in ('1','2','3','4','5')  
    GROUP BY user_id  
    HAVING COUNT(user_id_type)='16'  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want users with 3 IDs as long as one of the IDs is not D. How about;

```
select user
from table
group by user
having count(*) = 3 and max(ID) <> 'D'
```

The HAVING clause is useful in situations like this. This approach will work as long as the excluded ID is the max (or an easy change for min).

Following your comment, if the min/max(ID) approach isn't viable then you could use NOT IN;

```
select user
from table
where user not in (select user from table where ID = 'D')
group by user
having count(*) = 3
```

Following the updated question, if I've understood the mapping between the initial example and reality correctly then the query should be something like this;

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_id_type
WHERE user_id not in (select user_id from user_id_type where user_id_type in ('1','2','3','4','5'))
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id_type)='16'
```

What is odd is that you appear to have both a table and a column in the table with the same name 'user_id_type'. This isn't the clearest of designs.